# Error when trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails server with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, digital-ocean

I've been using [this](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04) tutorial to deploy a Ruby on rails application via digitalocean. I'm using a 512 MB Memory with 20 GB space on Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64.

However, at the end of the tutorial when I try to run `cap production deploy` I get this:

```
 [23e7b90d] Running [ -d $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1-p112 ] as deploy@example.com

 [23e7b90d] Command: [ -d $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1-p112 ]

 [a916b547] Running [ -d $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1-p112 ] as deploy@188.166.32.210

 [a916b547] Command: [ -d $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1-p112 ]
 DEBUG [a916b547] Finished in 0.418 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).

WARN rbenv: 2.3.1-p112 is not installed or not found in $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1-p112
```

EDIT 1:
I have installed ruby 2.3.1 on the server. When I ssh into the server and type ruby -v it gives me `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`

Here is my Capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

production.rb

```
# Simple Role Syntax
# ==================
# Supports bulk-adding hosts to roles, the primary
# server in each group is considered to be the first
# unless any hosts have the primary property set.
# Don't declare `role :all`, it's a meta role
role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}
role :web, %w{deploy@example.com}
role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}

# Extended Server Syntax
# ======================
# This can be used to drop a more detailed server
# definition into the server list. The second argument
# something that quacks like a hash can be used to set
# extended properties on the server.

# Replace 127.0.0.1 with your server's IP address!
server '188.166.32.210', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}
```

deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.4.1'

set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:royketelaar/myapp.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/myapp'

set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1-p112'

# Default value for :scm is :git
# set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }
set :bundle_env_variables, { 'NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES' => 1 }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  # desc 'Restart application'
  # task :restart do
  #   on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
  #     execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
  #   end
  # end

  # after :restart, :clear_cache do
  #   on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
  #     # Here we can do anything such as:
  #     # within release_path do
  #     #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
  #     # end
  #   end
  # end

end
```

gemfile (don't know if that's interesting)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'normalize-rails'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0' # Note: You MUST use 5.0.0 or greater for Rails 4.0+
gem 'devise'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'pg'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
gem 'capistrano-passenger'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Comment: Do you see the error? `rbenv: 2.3.1-p112 is not installed or not found`

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't mention it but I've already installed ruby 2.3.1 on the server. For some reason it still gives me this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for some reason I've fixed my error by changing a line in config/deploy.rb 
from `set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1-p112'`

to

`set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'`

I still don't know why though